# Can a Linux process/thread terminate without pass through do_exit()?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, exit, printk

To verify the behavior of a third party binary distributed software I'd like to use, I'm implementing a kernel module whose objective is to keep track of each child this software produces and terminates.

The target binary is a Golang produced one, and it is heavily multi thread.
The kernel module I wrote installs hooks on the kernel functions **_do_fork()** and  **do_exit()** to keep track of each process/thread this binary produces and terminates.

The LKM works, more or less.

During some conditions, however, I have a scenario I'm not able to explain.
It seems like a process/thread could terminate without passing through **do_exit()**.

The evidence I collected by putting **printk()** shows the process creation but does not indicate the process termination.

I'm aware that **printk()** can be slow, and I'm also aware that messages can be lost in such situations.

Trying to prevent message loss due to slow console (for this particular application, serial tty 115200 is used), I  tried to implement a quicker console, and messages have been collected using **netconsole**.

The described setup seems to confirm a process can terminate without pass through the **do_exit()** function.

But because I wasn't sure my messages couldn't be lost on the **printk()** infrastructure, I decided to repeat the same test but replacing **printk()** with **ftrace_printk()**, which should be a leaner alternative to **printk()**.

Still the same result, occasionally I see processes not passing through the **do_exit()**, and verifying if the PID is currently running, I have to face the fact that it is not running.

Also note that I put my hook in the **do_exit()** kernel function as the first instruction to ensure the function flow does not terminate inside a called function.

My question is then the following:

*Can a Linux process terminate without its flow pass through the **do_exit()** function?*

*If so, can someone give me a hint of what this scenario can be?*

Comment: Why don't you simply use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or perhaps [ptrace(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) maybe combined with [chroot(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html)? You don't need to write a kernel module..., unless you don't trust the kernel code

Comment: Also, what would happen to you if that Golang binary misbehave? How critical is your application (e.g. is it driving nuclear missiles or surgical robots)? Did you consider using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) on it? Without more details and more context, your question cannot be answered: it is a matter of opinion

Comment: A possibility could be to ask the provider of that Golang software to give you access to its source code. This of course requires some legal contract.

Comment: Yes, that could have been a lighter solution to my original problem. I chose to write a kernel module because I want to use it as the starting point of a more complex tool I have in mind. BTW, in this scenario ptrace and strace insert latencies that modify the target binary's flow. At this stage, I can't be sure if they somehow prevent the phenomena I observe using the LKM.

Comment: You cannot avoid [Heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) because of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)

Comment: At this moment, my target is no more binary behavior. I'm quite sure of what it is doing. My real concern now is to understand if my observations in the matter of do_exit() are accurate or not. The hook I put inside the do_exit() function is not reached (my function is not called). The printk() I put in the same pace does not produce any output. The logical conclusion would be: a process can be terminated without passing through do_exit(). But my understanding so far is that whatever a process stops because a signal or a voluntary termination must pass through do_exit().

Comment: Are you suggesting I'm observing a bug in the kernel? If this is the case, I'm still not able to explain why, after the program termination, without seeing a particular PID pass through the do_exit() function, I'm able to state it is terminated.

Comment: I don't know, because you are not giving enough details and context, with some [mre], in your question (which I believe is a matter of opinion and too vague). I still don't understand what would happen if something goes wrong in your scenario, and how much time and money can you afford spending

Comment: You could be interested in [CompCert](https://compcert.org/). You could replace the Linux kernel by your own (see [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/)...). You could patch both your [kernel](https://kernel.org/) and your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler to suite your needs (which so far remain secret), since they all are open source software

Comment: I understand your point, but as I stated in the question, my real issue is understand if my observations are reliable. My question, rather than the specific scenario, is more on the Linux kernel. If I'd have put straight my question, the answer I'm sure that would be: each process on Linux terminates by do_exit(). The scenario is there in the effort of avoiding the obvious answer, which I already know. If you know for sure that the obvious answer is the only applicable, I'm happy with this answer, and I'll direct my efforts somewhere else.

Comment: "my real issue is understand if my observations are reliable" -> no, they cannot be.

Comment: Sorry to be rude. You're still not answering my question. You marked my question as not accurate; it is your right beleive this. I can not prevent you from thinking whatever you want, but I put the question in the title, and before the end, I asked it again. You don't need to reproduce anything to answer the question. Fact is that you seem to be more concerned about why I need this information than answering the question. If you know the answer to my question, I'd be happy to read it from you.  If not, thank you for your time.

Comment: I mentioned several possibilities in comments. However, **I don't understand your question** (and the lack of some other answer may suggest that I am not alone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long debug session, I'm finally able to answer my own question.

That's not all; I'm also able to explain why I saw the strange behavior I described in my scenario.

Let's start from the beginning: monitoring a heavily multithreading application. I observed rare cases where a PID that suddenly stops exists without observing its flow to pass through the Linux Kernel **do_exit()** function.

Because this my original question:

*Can a Linux process terminate without pass through the do_exit() function?*

As for my current knowledge, which I would by now consider reasonably extensive, a Linux process can not end its execution without pass through the **do_exit()** function.

But this answer is in contrast with my observations, and the problem leading me to this question is still there.

Someone here suggested that the strange behavior I watched was because my observations were somehow wrong, alluding my method was inaccurate, as for my conclusions.

**My observations were correct**, and the process I watched didn't pass through the **do_exit()** but terminated.

To explain this phenomenon, I want to put on the table another question that I think internet searchers may find somehow useful:

*Can two processes share the same PID?*

If you'd asked me this a month ago, I'd surely answered this question with: "definitively no, two processes can not share the same PID."
Linux is more complex, though.

There's a situation in which, in a Linux system, two different processes can share the same PID!

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.20/source/fs/exec.c#L1141

Surprisingly, this behavior does not harm anyone; when this happens, one of these two processes is a zombie.

**updated to correct an error**

The circumstances of this duplicate PID are more intricate than those described previously. The process must flush the previous exec context if a threaded process forks before invoking an execve (the fork copies also the threads). If the intention is to use the execve() function to execute a new text, the kernel must first call the `flush_old_exec()`  function, which then calls the de_thread() function for each thread in the process other than the task leader. Except the task leader, all the process' threads are eliminated as a result. Each thread's PID is changed to that of the leader, and if it is not immediately terminated, for example because it needs to wait an operation completion, it keeps using that PID.

**end of the update**

That was what I was watching; the PID I was monitoring did not pass through the **do_exit()** because when the corresponding thread terminated, it had no more the PID it had when it started, but it had its leader's.

For people who know the Linux Kernel's mechanics very well, this is nothing to be surprised for; this behavior is intended and hasn't changed since 2.6.17.
Current 5.10.3, is still this way.

Hoping this to be useful to internet searchers; I'd also like to add that this also answers the followings:

- **Question**: Can a Linux process/thread terminate without pass through do_exit()? **Answer**: NO, do_exit() is the only way a process has to end its execution — both intentional than unintentional.
- **Question**: Can two processes share the same PID? **Answer**: Normally don't. There's some rare case in which two schedulable entities have the same PID.
- **Question**: Do Linux kernel have scenarios where a process change its PID? **Answer**: yes, there's at least one scenario where a Process changes its PID.

Answer (score -3):

> Can a Linux process terminate without its flow pass through the do_exit() function?

Probably not, but you should **study the source code of the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/)** to be sure. Ask on [KernelNewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/). Kernel threads and [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) or [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) related things (or perhaps `modprobe` or the older `hotplug`) are probable exceptions. When your `/sbin/init` of pid 1 terminates (that should not happen) strange things would happen.

> The LKM works, more or less.

What does that means? How could a kernel module half-work?

---

And in real life, it does happen sometimes that your Linux kernel is [panicking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic) or crashes (and it could happen with *your* LKM, if it has not been peer-reviewed by the Linux kernel community). In such a case, there is no more any notion of [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), since they are an abstraction provided by a living Linux kernel.

See also [dmesg(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html), [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [ptrace(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html), [clone(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [pthreads(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)

Look also inside the source code of your libc, e.g. [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/)

Of course, see [Linux From Scratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/) and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

> And verifying if the PID is currently running,

This can be done is user land with `/proc/`, or using [kill(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) with a 0 signal (and maybe also [pidfd_send_signal(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_send_signal.2.html)...)

PS. I still don't understand why you need to write a kernel module or change the kernel code. My intuition would be to avoid doing that when possible.

Comment: This, at last, is the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you for the time you dedicated to me. Allow me to comment on your answer, that you're not sure either. Before posting here, I did reasonably significant research by myself. Assuming that if there is another clean way for a PID to exit, it should do something that do_exit already does in its code, for example, I checked how many references exit_mm() has in the kernel code; just one. Similar others have been checked, but at last, I can't be sure the other clean way out, if it exists, can not implement what it needs from scratches.

Comment: But you did not mention any URL related to your researches in your answer. And you did not give your work context: are you coding a display for a museum or a shop, some web microservices, or are you coding a neurosurgery robot. Both could run Linux!

Comment: If you think this helps, I can describe what I did before posting my question. do_exit() is a complex function which calls some other function. Roughly its behavior is to mark the PID as not schedulable and then, one by one, release the resources the PID acquired during its life. I assumed that if there's another clean way to exit, it must release the resources either. So I verified the references to all do_exit() called functions inside the kernel code. Most of them are called only by it. Few others are called elsewhere, but as far as my understanding, these are not relevant. No URL used.

Comment: You certainly downloaded the kernel source code with an URL, and I guess that Linux 2.6 is not the same as Linux 5.3 on these aspects

Comment: The process exit is such a basic functionality that I do not even consider the Linux version could have a part. I give you that: I forgot to write the version I am using. My fault. It is the standard (github.com/torvalds) Linux 4.19.20. Are you aware of any changes in the processes exit behavior since Linux 2.6 that may be relevant to my question?

Comment: No, and that could be a different question to be asked on https://kernelnewbies.org/ - BTW 4.19 is a very old kernel, and you definitely should have mentioned that version in your question